# How can I trace a process to a file on a windows 7 32 bit laptop?

Tags: windows, process

I have a process running in my process list. I would like to know which file is responsible for running the process.

How can I trace it to a file?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what exactly you want to do, please describe it in full detail

Comment: @MichelZ I want to know which executable is running a process in memory.

Comment: Please delete the question as it doesn't fall into the realm of **professional** system administration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[With the Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).  Looking at procmon, and/or Process Explorer.

(That's assuming it's not trivial to discover with, say the Command Line column in Task Manager, of course - see below image.)

[image]